# number of surjective functions from n+1 elements to n elements

Tags: combinatorics

so I have this question...

[image: the question]

little background, my prof covers basics and gives hw that requires us to know more than he teaches lol. so ofc after looking through the lecture notes and seeing how it doesn't offer any help, I've been searching on how to solve this for like 3 hrs now and my brain feels like it's about to explode lol.

I've seen how to do 4 elements to 3 which doesn't help in my case with n+1 and n, and sth called stirling numbers of second kind?, but really doubt our prof is gonna make us use that to solve this... so.. after 3 hrs I'm still stuck :3

and note that I suck at combinatorics so baby language would be super appreciated <3

Comment: Try it with a few small cases and extrapolate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you have to choose two  elements with the same image, that you can do on ${n+1\choose 2}$ ways. Now if identify this two elements we have to find the number of bijective functions and that is $n!$. So you have $${n+1\choose 2}\cdot n!$$ functions.